# Domain name transferred now website down. Nameservers not changed

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, domain-name, domain-registration

Hi guys and Merry Christmas.

Got an email from a client late on Christmas Eve (joy) saying their website was down. We are looking to create a new site for them and take their hosting in the process. We have had issues with their existing hosting company in getting the domain name transferred with them dragging their heels and coming up with excuses as to problems. We finally got the domain name transferred to the new host on 21st December. Doing a whois I can see the new registrar details and I received a message from the registration company that the domain had been transferred.

I should point out that we decided to leave the existing website in place for the time being and get the new one set up before changing the name servers over. The name servers are still the old ones and haven't been touched but the website is now down and I don't know whether the cause is down to the domain transfer or whether there is a problem with the name server.

Checking the DNS Record on network-tools.com returns:

```
DNS servers
ns67.1and1.co.uk [217.160.80.173]
DNS server returned an error: Name server failed
```

Would this suggest a problem with the name server or can I do something with the domain to resolve this?

The domain is eyres-furniture.com

Comment: Could you please give us your DNS configuration ?

Comment: Added the domain to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the transfer the old registrar removed the name entries from their name servers.

But without giving at least the domain name nobody can help you further.

Comment: According to the DNS protocol the `SERVFAIL` error being sent by 1&1 is incorrect.  An authoritative server should give `REFUSED` when asked for a domain name that it's not serving.  `SERVFAIL` is supposed to indicate a temporary error at the server.

Comment: @Alnitak so this is a permanent thing related to mailq's answer answer? Best thing to do is set up the new hosting account and point the domain at the new hosts nameservers or is there a way to point the domain at the existing website still?

Comment: @MattAsbury You can point at the existing website using new name servers, if that works best for you - does the new registrar offer DNS services?

Answer (score 1):

From the little relevant detail you posted it would appear you have but a single DNS server for the domain and it's not responding to DNS queries. Even if the domain zone had been removed from that server it should still provide a response, essentially one saying "not my domain, go look elsewhere".

Answer (score 0):

1and1 is not working anymore for your domain. Why it happened is a separate question (likely it's just what mailq suggested).

What you need to resolve the issue is - provide some new nameservers for the domain in question. Your options:

1. Your **old** webhosting may already have nameservers set-up for you domain. Try querying the hosting nameservers for your domain, if you get good answer - use them.
2. Your new registrar normally provides nameservers.
3. Any 3-rd party DNS hosting (see [the list](http://talkdns.info/list)).
4. Your new webhosting may provide nameservers, but probably it's easier not to mess with it.

Once you have nameservers, configure A records for eyres-furniture.com and www.eyres-furniture.com - they should point to the old webhosting (if it's still active) and also MX records for mailserver that handles mail for the domain.

Finally tell your registrar (normally via web control panel) to use the new nameservers.